# Can I travel to Australia on the eVisitor visa for a short-term period of studying? If not, what visa can I use?

Tags: visas, australia, study, italian-citizens

I'm an italian M.Sc. student. I have an agreement with a professor of the Australian National University for performing (part of) my master thesis abroad.

I will have to stay in Australia for less than 3 months (as then I'll have to come back home to graduate) and I have no plans of working. I will not be awarded any academic title by the Australian National University.

I would like to know what is the visa the better suits my situation. I was thinking to the eVisitor visa (apparently I meet all the requirements - even though it is not very clear whether I can study or not - and it's free!), but I'm not sure whether I'm actually eligible or if there are other visas that better suits my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact limitations of the eVisitor (subclass 651) visa are listed in the "[Migration Regulation 1994](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2016C00413/Html/Volume_4#_Toc449959896)" act:

> **651.611**
>
> Conditions **8115**, **8201**, **8527** and **8528** must be imposed.

The description of these conditions is spelled out in the [Visa conditions](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2016C00413/Html/Volume_6#_Toc449961421) section:

1. > **8115**
   >
   > The holder must not work in Australia other than by engaging in a business visitor activity.
2. > **8201**
   >
   > (1)  While in Australia, the holder must not engage, for more than 3 months, in any studies or training.
3. > **8527**
   >
   > The holder must be free from tuberculosis at the time of travel to, and entry into, Australia.
4. > **8528**
   >
   > The holder must not have one or more criminal convictions, for which the sentence or sentences (whether served or not) are for a total period of 12 months duration or more, at the time of travel to, and entry into, Australia.

Therefore you are free to study in Australia under the eVisitor visa, as long as you don't do it for more than 3 months.